# How many isomeres of sucrose can we use?

Tags: human-biology

It appears that of sucrose (C12H22O11) there are about 512 possible structures (nine carbon atoms are asymmetric= 2^9). And only one of this 512 forms taste sweet. Now it is known that human can't use all isomeres of amino acids but how many forms of sucrose can we digest or use in the glycolysis for our energy?

Comment: How did you come up with the number 512?  To my knowledge, the variants of glucose are (1) D and L stereoisomers (2) the pyranose and furanose forms, and (3) alpha and beta stereoisomers at carbon 1.  Any combination of these can occur, so there are 2*2*2 = 8 cyclic forms. Plus the linear form, caused by the ring opening.  But then the pyranose/furanose and alpha/beta isomers interconvert spontaneously in water solution via the linear form (ring opening/closing), so the only biochemically distinct forms are D and L. I think.

Comment: This question is totally confused. Assuming the questioner means hexoses, there are 16 isomers of aldohexose. I have no idea what the sentence about "human can't use all isomers of proteins" means — possibly amino acids? And glucose is not used in the citric acid cycle. Perhaps the questioner means glycolysis. Unless the question is revised I shall vote to close it as unclear.